# How do I access individual words after splitting a string?

Tags: c++

```
std::string token, line("This is a sentence.");
std::istringstream iss(line);
getline(iss, token, ' ');

std::cout << token[0] << "\n";
```

This is printing individual letters. How do I get the complete words?

Updated to add:

I need to access them as words for doing something like this...

```
if (word[0] == "something")
   do_this();
else
   do_that();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
std::string token, line("This is a sentence.");
std::istringstream iss(line);
getline(iss, token, ' ');

std::cout << token << "\n";
```

To store all the tokens:

```
std::vector<std::string> tokens;
while (getline(iss, token, ' '))
    tokens.push_back(token);
```

or just:

```
std::vector<std::string> tokens;
while (iss >> token)
    tokens.push_back(token);
```

Now `tokens[i]` is the `i`th token.

Comment: Then how do I access it by word? I mean like

if (word[1] == "blah")
  //do something

if (word[2] == "blah")
  // do something else

Comment: If you do this, you might as well use `iss >> token`, which will also get words separated by other whitespace characters.

Answer (score 2):

You would first have to ***define what makes a word***.

If it's ***whitespace***, `iss >> token` is the default option:

```
std::string line("This is a sentence.");
std::istringstream iss(line);

std::vector<std::string> words. 
std::string token;
while(iss >> token)
  words.push_back(token);
```

This should find

```
This
is
a
sentence.
```

as words.

If it's anything more complicated than whitespace, you will have to write your own lexer.

Comment: @thorvald: I've adapted the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your token variable is a String, not an array of strings.  By using the [0], you're asking for the first character of token, not the String itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just print token, and do the getline again.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `token` to be a `std::string`, which uses the index operator `[]` to return an individual character.  In order to output the entire string, avoid using the index operator.